# How to use a Buefy navbar with a Vue 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3, bulma, buefy

I made my first Vue project and everything works fine but it's ugly, so now I want to improve it by using Buefy.

I followed the instructions but I can't get it to work, I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'use' of undefined

I installed it and wrote this code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

Vue.use(Buefy)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Buefy (v0.9.8) supports Vue 2 but does not support Vue 3 .